# regex for matching particular word in whole sentence using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want a regex in perl that can strip the word in capitals from the given sentence 
"Device from XML database". I can say that the whole sentence can change in future including the spaces present now. Only the "xml" word is fixed and all the stuff around it is volatile. So i want a strong regex that can withstand any changes in number of spaces and words before/after "xml" word.

Comment: So, from "Device from XML database", you want the output to be "Device from xml database", and for other strings you want any fully-capitalized words to be lower-cased? If that's the case, I would recommend against regex, in favor of a regular string-to-array, and foreach loop approach to the problem.

Comment: It sounds to me like he wants to end up with "Device from database", but maybe not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$string = "Device from XML database";
$string =~ s/\bXML\b\s//;

That'll grab one space after XML as well..

Comment: Since the "whole sentence can change in the future," your `s///` will not change `"Device from database: XML."`  An s///g (to handle possible multiple "XML" instances) sans the `\s` may be closer to what Nightfirecat wants.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the word boundary anchor \b: `\bXML\b`

Comment: Remember that this will cause problems for text like "This is XML's wa y of doing things." This sort of natural language processing is very complicated.